# cpp-netlib hello world example wont compile on linux

Tags: c++, linux, cpp-netlib

I tried to run the hello world example on cpp-netlib.org using cpp-netlib-0.12.0 and boost-1.64.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. A piece of the code is (from line 1):

```
#include <boost/network/protocol/http/server.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace http = boost::network::http;

struct hello_world;
typedef http::server<hello_world> server;

struct hello_world
{
    void operator()(server::request const &request, server::response &response)
    {
        server::string_type ip = source(request);
        unsigned int port = request.source_port;
        std::ostringstream data;
        data << "Hello, " << ip << ':' << port << '!';
        response = server::response::stock_reply(server::response::ok, data.str());
    }
    void log(const server::string_type& message)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << message << std::endl;
    }
};
```

and when I use the following line to compile:

```
g++ test1.cpp -o test1 -std=c++11 -lcppnetlib-uri -lcppnetlib-server-parsers -lcppnetlib-client-connections -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread
```

I get the following error:

```
test1.cpp:11:61: error: ‘boost::network::http::server<hello_world>::response’ has not been declared
     void operator()(server::request const &request, server::response &response)
                                                             ^
test1.cpp: In member function ‘void hello_world::operator()(const request&, int&)’:
test1.cpp:17:28: error: ‘boost::network::http::server<hello_world>::response’ has not been declared
         response = server::response::stock_reply(server::response::ok, data.str());
                            ^
test1.cpp:17:58: error: ‘boost::network::http::server<hello_world>::response’ has not been declared
         response = server::response::stock_reply(server::response::ok, data.str());
                                                          ^
```

I took the code right out of the example from the website. I checked the include paths and all the necessary libraries appear to be there. I cant seem to figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like documentation for cpp-netlib is all messed up (just like the whole project in general). [HTTP server API page](http://cpp-netlib.org/0.12.0/reference/http_server.html) insists that `Handler` template parameter for `http::server` should have member `operator ()` taking `connection_ptr` as second parameter (though it suggests wrong include):

```cpp
#include <boost/network/protocol/http/server.hpp>
#include <boost/network/utils/thread_pool.hpp>

struct handler_type;
typedef boost::network::http::server<handler_type> http_server;

struct handler_type
{
    void
    operator ()
    (
        http_server::request const & request,
        http_server::connection_ptr  connection
    )
    {
        // do something here
    }
};
```